# Using Facebook login to sign in Facebook users

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having trouble integrating Facebook login into my website as it gives me an error :

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains.

Also the code in config.php is:

```
<?php
session_start();
$appID='Your App Id';
$appSecret='Your App Secret';
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='localhost'){
$base_url='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}else{
$base_url='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
}
?>
```

I found the tutorial from http://www.idiotminds.com/login-with-facebook-using-php-sdk/

The site URL in Facebook app is: http://www.angeloscleanthous.com/chat/facebook/

The canvas URL is the same with the site URL.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If the Site URL in facebook app is:http://www.angeloscleanthous.com/chat/facebook/

then

You have to access the facebook api code via

http://www.angeloscleanthous.com/chat/facebook/

In other words, When you will put the Site Url on your browser, then your code that access facebook api should run.

Comment: well unfortunately it doesn't run

Comment: In your code "localhost" is mentioned.Are you testing the code at local right now?

Comment: no am testing this at http://www.angeloscleanthous.com/chat/facebook/index.php. this is were the button is.

Comment: i have changed the line to if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='http://www.angeloscleanthous.com/chat/faceboook/') but is not working

Comment: insted of angeloscleanthous.com/chat/facebook/index.php use angeloscleanthous.com/chat/facebook otherwise regenerate the app secret key and try again.

Comment: Then try Facebook SDK for PHP first and if it works then try this one you are using.

Comment: what u talking about? isnt the same thing?

Comment: Facebook PHP SDK is redirect you to login page if every thing is ok without any change.just place your settings there and test every thing is ok.

Comment: hello i did what you asked but now istead of gettng hello "username" after granting permission i get "The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF." Do you know why?

Comment: Ok it means your error of sITE URL at least not the issue now.Now just    regenerate the app keys and try again.hope so your facebook login is not blocked because of wrong login attempts.

Comment: OK facebook SDK for me now so i dont have to use alternative ways